# getConnectedNodes direction parameter

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a small issue with the parameter `direction` of the function `getConnectedNodes()` based on the [Vis.js documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html?keywords=getConnected) (search for "getConnectedNodes" in the link)

Any idea to get the direction of the edges using the parameter (i don't know how to)?

**JSON Example**

```
[ 
  { "x": 0, "y": 0, "id": "0", "connections": [ 2 ] // i think here should be a from?},
  { "x": 200, "y": 0, "id": "1", "connections": [ 3, 2 ] },
  { "x": 500, "y": 500, "id": "2", "connections": [ 0, 1 ] },
  { "x": 300, "y": -200, "id": "3", "connections": [ 1 ] } 
]
```

Here part of the code

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options)).sample();

let network;

function init() {
  container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  exportArea = document.getElementById('input_output');
  network = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => {network = new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options);}).sample();
};

function addConnections(elem, index) {
  elem.connections = network.getConnectedNodes(index);               < I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE
}

function exportNetwork() {
  var nodes = objectToArray(network.getPositions());
  nodes.forEach(addConnections);
  var exportValue = JSON.stringify(nodes, undefined, 2);
  exportArea.innerHTML = exportValue;
}

function objectToArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    obj[key].id = key;
    return obj[key];
  });
}
```

Before hand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is the index of the array like `0, 1, 2,,,`. The start index is `0`. On the other hand, `elem` is the object like `{x: ###, y: ###, id: ###}`. From these situation, I thought that `index` of `getConnectedNodes(index)` might be `elem.id`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
elem.connections = network.getConnectedNodes(index);
```

#### To:

```
elem.connections = network.getConnectedNodes(elem.id, "from");
```

- From [the document](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html), if you want to retrieve "parent", you can retrieve it by adding `from` to the argument.

  > - For a node id, returns an array with the id's of the connected nodes.
  > - If optional parameter direction is set to string 'from', only parent nodes are returned.
  > - If direction is set to 'to', only child nodes are returned.
  > - Any other value or undefined returns both parent and child nodes.
- When you want to retrieve "child", please add `to` to the argument instead of `from`.

Comment: Based on the [Vis.js documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html?keywords=getConnected) with the `getConnectedNodes(String, nodeId or edgeId,` `[String direction]` i can get only the child or parent nodes. Your solution still return all the connected nodes, not the parent or child ones (direction). Do you know how to write the parameters to get that result?

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. You want to retrieve "parent". I could understand like this. By this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.